# Absolute positioning of navbar in Twitter bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The `fixed navbar` in bootstrap is not `absolute in position`. When using `fixed navbars` the markup below the navbars appears right on the header navbar. How to overcome this:

I tried `position:absolute` and also a `margin from top equal to size of navbar header height.` Nothing is working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please, post some code

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle link for your code

Comment: Do you want the navbar to stay stuck to the top of your page as you scroll or not?

Answer (score 6):

Bootstrap provides option to be fixed at the top

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    ...
  </div>
</nav>
```

reference: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top
**OR**
You can use `absolute` to be fixed at the top and add same height navbar as body `padding-top` 
for example

```
.navbar{
  height: 50px;
}
body{
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In bootstrap 4, use **fixed-top** instead of `navbar-fixed-top`:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light bg-faded">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed top</a>
</nav>
```